# is it possible to convert bitset<8> to an array of characters of integers?

Tags: c++, bitset, bitsets

I have `bitset<8> v8` and its value is something like "11001101", something in binary, how can we convert it to an array of characters or integers in c++?

Comment: How do you want `11001101` to be interpreted? each digit as one char (and one int)?

Comment: each digit as one character, because i want to make a matrix, for that i will need each as a character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert to an array of char, you could use the `bitset::to_string()` function to obtain the string representation and then copy individual characters from that string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
int main()
{
        std::bitset<8> v8 = 0xcd;

        std::string v8_str = v8.to_string();
        std::cout << "string form: " << v8_str << '\n';

        char a[9] = {0}; 
        std::copy(v8_str.begin(), v8_str.end(), a);
        // or even strcpy(a, v8_str.c_str());
        std::cout << "array form: " << a << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> ints;
for(int i = 0 ; i < v8.size() ; i++ )
{
     ints.push_back(v8[i]);
}
```

Likewise, you can make an array of chars. Or you may use raw array as:

```
char chars[8];
for(int i = 0 ; i < v8.size() ; i++ )
{
     chars[i] = v8[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if I use cout to display them, it doesnt gives correct answer